# Is each completely minimal topological group minimal?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups

A topological group $G$ is called

$\bullet$ *minimal* if it admits no strictly weaker Hausdorff group topology;

$\bullet$ *completely minimal* if it is Raikov-complete in each weaker Hausdorff group topology.

It is easy to see that each  Raikov-complete minimal topological group is completely minimal and each completely minimal topological group is Raikov-complete.

**Problem.** Is each completely minimal topological group minimal? Equivalently, is an  topological group completely minimal if and only if it is minimal and Raikov-complete?

**Remark.** The answer to this problem is affirmative for [$\omega$-narrow topological groups of countable pseudocharacter](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.10127) and also for [Abelian topological groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05411).

Comment: check thm 3.7 in Categorically compact topological groups by Dikranjan and Uspenskij http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404996001399

Comment: @UriBader Thank you for the reference to the paper of Dikranjan-Uspenski. This theorem is the proof of the statement in Remark 2. So Problems 1,2 concerns injectivity of the homomorphisms.

Comment: @ThomasRot The group $\mathbb Z$ dmits an injective homomorphism with non-closed image into the circle group.

Comment: The definition is about $G$ which doesn't appear in the actual definition.

Comment: @Asasf-Karagila Thank you for the remark. I have corrected this misprint.

Comment: Again, more classics though about this before. The statement in Remark 2 was also proved by Protasov and Zelenyuk  in Theorem 4.3 of [PZ]. Their following Question 4.4 is your Problem for abelian groups ([PZ]  is [Complementable topologies on abelian groups](https://www.emis.de/journals/SMZ/2001/03/550.pdf)*, Siberian Math. Jour., 42:3 (May – June 2001), 550-560, (in Russian)).

Comment: @Alex-Ravsky Thanks, Sasha for the reference to [PZ]-paper. Rodina dolzhna znat svoih geroev!